# fade out after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the same behaviour as stackoverflow's.

In SO, after we click the unread inbox, which is red in color and if we click any where else, it fades out.

I have this html:

```
<small class="notifi pull-right">1</small>
```

And I'm currently doing:

```
    $('small.pull-right').click(function () {
        var that = this;
        $(document).one('click', function () {
            $(that).hide('fade');
        });
    });
```

But, it isn't working. After the `<small>` is clicked, a dropdown opens. Thats fine. After that if a user clicks somewhere else, it should fade out.

So, what should I?

Comment: Just a little off-topic, `<small>` shouldn't be used. Use a `<span>` and style it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**html code**

```
<small class="notifi pull-right">1</small>
```

**jQuery**

```
   $('.pull-right').click(function () {
        var that = this;
        $(document).one('click', function () {
            $(that).hide('fade');
        });
    });
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/9z6N2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You also have a typo here:

```
$('small.notify.pull-right')
```

It has to be

```
$('small.notifi.pull-right')
```

Here a running demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hnz5p/

I would write:

```
var button = $('small.notifi.pull-right');
button.click(function () {
    $(document).one('click', function () {
        button.fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Hit Me

$("#smallid").click(function () {

```
    $("#smallid").fadeOut();
});
```